# How do I remove the shortcut that pops open the sound System Settings tab? (opt + volume)

Tags: macos, mac, shortcut

If I select <kbd>Option</kbd> + Volume (up, down or mute), then my Mac's Sound preference tab from System Settings opens up. I'd like to remove this functionality.

I've looked inside Settings -> Keyboard -> Keyboard Shortcuts but can't find this option nor a way to unassign it. How do I remove this shortcut or reassign it?

Comment: I think this is 'baked in' to macOS and can't be changed.

Comment: Yeah, I'm thinking the same thing; strange design when the other shortcuts are configurable.